# Launch 7zip and fetch the output from the console

Tags: command-line, freepascal, 7zip

In a Lazarus (freepascal) project I added a TAsyncProcess with those options: `[poUsePipes,poStderrToOutPut]` to catch the output and show the last line.

using the `ReadData` event, I added some code that show the last line if I grab some text:

```
procedure TForm1.AsyncProcess1ReadData(Sender: TObject);
var
  aOutput: TStringList;
  iCpt: integer;
  sLine: string;
begin
  aOutput := TStringList.Create();
  aOutput.LoadFromStream(AsyncProcess1.Output);

  if (aOutput.Count > 0) then
  begin
    setStatus(aOutput.Strings[aOutput.Count-1]);
  end;
end;
```

then I tryed to get the last non-empty line:

```
procedure TForm1.AsyncProcess1ReadData(Sender: TObject);
var
  aOutput: TStringList;
  iCpt: integer;
  sLine: string;
begin
  aOutput := TStringList.Create();
  aOutput.LoadFromStream(AsyncProcess1.Output);

  if (aOutput.Count > 0) then
  begin
    // Get the last non-empty line
    for iCpt := (aOutput.Count-1) to 0 do
    begin
      sLine := aOutput.Strings[iCpt];
      if Length(Trim(sLine)) > 0 then
      begin
        setStatus(sLine);
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Both shows nothing. I've used the first code with ffmpeg with success.
Thanks!

Comment: It works fine for me using `7-Zip 9.20 64-bit` on `Windows 7 64-bit` compiled on `Lazarus 0.9.30.2`. Could you include the `TAsyncProcess.CommandLine` you've executed ?

Comment: I can show you the whole code: http://pastebin.com/mz6JC0an . I have `7-Zip [64] 9.25 alpha`

Comment: Could you paste also the `umain.lfm` file ? It will simplify me building the whole form.

Comment: try: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ddvw5eucfqgpr0/Backup.zip